# Sharepoint Server 2010/2013 installation

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

This is not really a problem... I have a developper profile and I was asked to estimate how would it cost to install Sharepoint 2010 on a Windows 2008 VM?

So, basically, I would like to know by your past experiences, how long does it take to install Sharepoint Server 2010 on a new Windows 2008 VM.

Is it the same duration for Sharepoint 2013?

Should I expect to run into multiple problems as this will be my first install?

Answer (score 2):

It takes about 15 minutes to install.

Now, I assume you're asking about post-install configuration. That can take *weeks* depending on the requirements, which you have not mentioned.

Comment: What MDMarra said. Installation is trivial. Configuration to turn it into something useful will take considerably longer and isn't something we can estimate for you because it depends hugely on your sharepoint farm topology and how you intend to use it afterwards. Of course you can accept all the defaults and you'll *probably* end up with something that *sort-of* works afterwards, providing you don't put too much load on it and don't mind performance absolutely sucking... but most people tend not to want that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is not difficult to install Sharepoint 2010 even 2013 in a testing environment. If you want to install for a production and enterprise environment you should have some kind of experience installing it on a server farm. The installation isnt't difficult, but the pre and post install is.